# Delete a homescreen on Motorola Moto G

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, home-screen, delete, motorola-moto-g

I wondered how I could remove an empty homescreen on a Motorola Moto G with Android 4.4 (Kitkat)..
I tried to de-zoom, like I used to do with my older android phone (galaxy S3), but it doesn't work. ;(

Cheers

Comment: Are you using the Google Experience Launcher?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove home screen in Moto G as it contains Stock version of android. You can do that with third party launchers like [Go Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex), [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there's nothing you can do since it's a stock launcher.
Try downloading a different launcher from the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually. You just have to keep on removing widgets and shortcut icons untill there are none left on the screen, and it will automatically remove itself – unless its the last screen left. :-)